# How to create eclipse project from Play activator Template

Tags: eclipse, playframework, typesafe-activator

How to create Eclipse project from new Activator template. I tried executing eclipse command from the root of the project template but it does not work.

Comment: When I tried from Activator UI I get the following error.

Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
Not a valid project ID: eclipse
Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You must add first an "eclispe.sbt" file in the "project" folder :

```
// project/eclipse.sbt :
// This plugin adds commands to generate IDE project files
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")
```

Then you could run "./activator eclipse"